# IDOC Listener granted message delivery

Tags: idoc, boomi, sap-r3

We're working on a project in SAP ERP R/3 where the SAP team delivers document notifications via SAP router. We've attached a listener on that port using Dell Boomi, which under the hood uses the official SAP Java connector.

When things are OK (network is up, our listener server is up etc...) we receive the IDocs but when the network is down or our server is being rebooted the IDocs seem to be "lost".

I don't have any SAP understanding but I wonder if there is any way to grant the delivery of such IDocs. E.g. some queueing options in SAP which would retry pending IDocs until success?

Answer (score 0):

you can schedule report `RSARFCEX` in the SAP system to re-execute transactional RFCs that failed due to connection problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard functionality for troubleshooting IDocs, [ALE Status Monitor](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/d4/0d67e4d85511d2a6080060087832f8/content.htm). It allows to trace failed IDocs, correct them and retry (process) the corrected ones again. Tcode is `BD87`.